# How to use ggplot2 to plot box plots from Boruta's results in R

Tags: r

I have more than a hundred variables, if I use the plot function to plot the box plot, the readability is very poor, I want to use ggplot2 to plot

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code for the [`plot.Boruta()`](https://gitlab.com/mbq/Boruta/-/blob/main/R/tools.R) boxplot function, there is a fair amount of data manipulation taking place before it can be plotted. Here is one example where I conducted the various data manipulations and altered the code to output a dataframe, which can then be passed to ggplot2 for plotting:

```r
#install.packages("Boruta")
library(Boruta)
library(mlbench)

data(HouseVotes84)
na.omit(HouseVotes84)->hvo
Boruta(Class~.,data=hvo,doTrace=2)->Bor.hvo
#>  1. run of importance source...
#>  2. run of importance source...
#>  3. run of importance source...
...
#>  98. run of importance source...
#>  99. run of importance source...

print(Bor.hvo)
#> Boruta performed 99 iterations in 6.091485 secs.
#>  11 attributes confirmed important: V11, V12, V13, V14, V15 and 6 more;
#>  4 attributes confirmed unimportant: V1, V10, V16, V6;
#>  1 tentative attributes left: V2;
plot(Bor.hvo)
```

[image]

Create a custom 'Boruta data cleaning' function:

```r
process_the_Boruta_data <- function(x, whichShadow=c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE),
                                    colCode=c('green','yellow','red','blue'),
                                    col=NULL) {
  if(is.null(x$ImpHistory))
    stop('Importance history was not stored during the Boruta run.')
  
  #Removal of -Infs and conversion to a list
  lz <- lapply(1:ncol(x$ImpHistory),
               function(i) x$ImpHistory[is.finite(x$ImpHistory[,i]),i])
  colnames(x$ImpHistory) -> names(lz)
  
  #Selection of shadow meta-attributes
  numShadow <- sum(whichShadow)
  lz[c(rep(TRUE,length(x$finalDecision)),whichShadow)] -> lz
  
  generateCol<-function(x,colCode,col,numShadow){
    #Checking arguments
    if(is.null(col) & length(colCode)!=4)
      stop('colCode should have 4 elements.')
    #Generating col
    if(is.null(col)){
      rep(colCode[4],length(x$finalDecision)+numShadow)->cc
      cc[c(x$finalDecision=='Confirmed',rep(FALSE,numShadow))]<-colCode[1]
      cc[c(x$finalDecision=='Tentative',rep(FALSE,numShadow))]<-colCode[2]
      cc[c(x$finalDecision=='Rejected',rep(FALSE,numShadow))]<-colCode[3]
      col=cc
    }
    return(col)
  }
  
  #Generating color vector
  col <- generateCol(x, colCode, col, numShadow)
  
  #Ordering boxes due to attribute median importance
  ii<-order(sapply(lz,stats::median))
  lz[ii] -> lz
  col <- col[ii]
  lz_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lz)
  df <- as.data.frame(t(lz_df))
  names(df) <- names(lz)
  rownames(df) <- NULL
  return(df)
}

# Apply the function:
clean_Bor.hvo <- process_the_Boruta_data(Bor.hvo)

# Plot the data:
library(tidyverse)
clean_Bor.hvo %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(name, value, median), y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,
                                   vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I succeeded in following your suggestion.